# Why does this trick for the binomial theorem for negative exponents work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

The "trick" for solving a binomial with a negative index is given by:

[image]

I understand how to expand binomials of the form $1+x$ for negative indices, but I do not why this method of factoring works for binomials of form $a+x$ with negative exponents.

(Note:  I have not yet learned Newton's Binomial Theorem but I have learned the case for $1+a$ with negative integers, so please do not include Newton's Therem in your answer if it's possible. Also, I understand that they have divided the binomial by $a$ or $x$ in each expression but I don't understand the factors that have been taken out.)

Lately, I have noticed that if I express the binomial expression as a reciprocal with positive powers the answer maintains correct, but I'm not certain if this is valid for all negative exponents.

Comment: What's the question, exactly? From $a+x=a \cdot (1+x/a)$ it follows that $(a+x)^n=a^n \cdot (1+x/a)^n$, if that's the step that you don't understand.

Comment: @Hans that's all I needed, thanks.

Comment: although, late to ask; but if could please tell the source of the material from which it is quoted.